# Hive jdbc driver issue

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to execute a "**LOAD DATA INPATH**" query using the JDBC Hive driver on a Hortonworks HDP 2.6 cluster. The destination table is an ORC partitioned table for which I specified the HDFS location.

The query actually executes correctly (the files are moved into the destination directory and can be queried), but the driver method **Statement.execute()** returns false. No exception is raised. Looking at the hive logs, I can see that only one error is displayed in the process:

> hdfs.KeyProviderCache
>   (KeyProviderCache.java:createKeyProviderURI(87)) - Could not find uri
>   with key [dfs.encryption.key.provider.uri] to create a keyProvider !!

Could it be the issue? Seems related to the at-rest encryption, which is disabled on the cluster.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: That's just a mis-labeled and mis-qualified message -- will be fixed in your next Hadoop upgrade, cf. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-7931 -- for now, just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can I assume the query executed fine if no exception is raised even if the method returned false?

Comment: **RTFM** - method `execute()` returns False to indicate that the query did not return any result to the driver -- which is always the case for an "INSERT" or "LOAD" command (but for a "SELECT" or "SHOW" query, it would return True, even with zero records) >> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-

Comment: My bad, I was not aware of that behavior. Thank you for pointing it out.